# Access - Multiple Criteria On Multiple Fields - Only Exclude Specific Match

Tags: sql, ms-access

Example

```
Sku     Qty
Apple   1
Orange  1
Apple   3
Orange  4
```

I want to exclude anything that is Exactly Orange* with a qty of 1.

If I do

```
WHERE ((QTY)>1) AND ((SKU) NOT "Orange")
```

the result would be:

```
Apple   3
```

I need the result:

```
Sku     Qty
Apple   1
Apple   3
Orange  4
```

Comment: What you ask for and your results are not consistent.

Comment: Updated, sorry for the confusion. I'm trying to exclude all oranges with qty of 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I assume that you really mean "not orange with quantity 1", then use;

```
where not (sku = "Orange" and qty = 1)
```

This is logically equivalent to:

```
where sku <> "Orange" or qty <> 1
```

Comment: I ended up using the bottom formula for this task. My comment to anyone using this is make sure to include parenthesis for this to work if you need to combine multiple conditions inside the WHERE statements with this. WHERE (sku <> "Orange" or qty <> 1) AND (sku <> "Apple" or qty <> 1)

Comment: @Charles That is because the `and` operator has precedence over `or`, therefore, without the parentheses, the `where` clause is evaluated as `WHERE sku <> "Orange" or (qty <> 1 AND sku <> "Apple") or qty <> 1`